# Archimedes Classic Proof for Area of Circle: Love it but can't grasp one aspect...

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

The proof assumes that:...

The perimeter of any CIRCUMSCRIBED regular polygon is GREATER than the circumference of the circle.

ie:

!http://www.themathpage.com/atrig/Trig_IMG/eval1.gif

Is this an axiom?
Is there a fundamental property I'm missing?
Does the answer to this depend on the definition of how one measures a circumference?

Please advise! :)

Comment: If you're proving a statement about the area, where does the perimeter come in?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Circle/Proof_3

Comment: Check Lemma 3:

The proof assumes c<q (where c is the circumference and q is the perimeter of the regular polygon)

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that for a given area, a circle has the shortest, or most compact, perimeter.

Given this information we can use the common notion, as referenced by Euclid, that the part is less than the whole.

Because the polygon the circle is circumscribed within contains the circle, its area must be larger, and therefore its perimeter must be larger.

Archimedes could have used this to derive pi or area to an approximate amount using straight lines.